# How to undo apt-get autoremove

Tags: apt, package-management, opencv

I just walked into the trap of calling

```
sudo apt-get install autoremove
```

I did it because I was unable to install `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev` because of `unmet dependencies`.
Now my [ros-indigo](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu) installation is broke, `opencv` is still not installed and I also cannot reinstall it.

When trying to install it I get only

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I fear that I'm really close to killing my entire package-dependency system. Can someone help me please?

Can I somehow use the file `/var/log/apt` to reverse the step of deleting ros?

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: Also this is giving me an error: `Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 18):

I don't Know if there is any simpler way but if you look at `/var/log/apt/history.log` you can see what was removed. Just reinstall each package that was removed.

Using this may save your time

```
echo '#!/bin/bash' > restore
echo sudo apt-get install `grep Remove /var/log/apt/history.log | tail -1 | sed -e 's|Remove: ||g' -e 's|([^)]*)||g' -e 's|:[^ ]* ||g' -e 's|,||g'` >> restore
chmod +x restore 
./restore
```

Comment: this is a giant list of the form `Commandline: apt-get autoremove
Remove: ros-indigo-tf:amd64 (1.11.7-0trusty-20160111-112853-0800), ros-indigo-xacro:amd64 (1.9.5-0trusty-20160110-105433-0800),` ... and so on (ca 1000 entries). Rewriting everything in the form `sudo apt-get install  ros-indigo-tf:amd64 ros-indigo-xacro:amd64` ... can become very tedious. Isn't there an automatic command to install them ?

Comment: Also the error `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.` troubles me. Can I find out where it exactly comes from (which package) ?

Comment: answer was edited

Comment: Thanks, but there is still something broke :(.
`Package libswresample0 is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
E: Package 'libswresample0' has no installation candidate`

Comment: Commenting here so I don't lose this.  +1  Can't tell you how many times I have ran autoremove and it removed something I needed to keep.  This was very simple to run and worked flawless.  Thank you!

Comment: This was the first time `autoremove` actually removed something useful and my computer became useless.  Your solution solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: This is gold! Thanks for saving me a bunch of time. `autoremove` nuked my python environments.

Comment: Just needed a reboot after running the OPs command

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ROS and the other answer does not fix the problem completely, you can go to your workspace and do:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y
```